# supremum of $P(|Y-\mu_Y|\geq \alpha)$

Tags: probability-theory

By Chebychev's inequality, $P(|Y-\mu_Y|\geq \alpha) \leq \frac{Var(Y)}{\alpha^2}$.

I would like to ask whether $\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ is the supremum of  $\{P(|Y-\mu_Y|\geq \alpha): Y \text{ is RV}, Var(Y)=1\}$

Thanks.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the correction. The supremum shouldn't be dependent to $Y$. I have made the changed on fixing $Var(Y)=1$ so the sup is no longer dependent to RV itself.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Sharpness_of_bounds Does this answer your question?

Comment: @PhysMath That's exactly what I want! Thanks for helping!